# Is there a formula to sum cells in a row that are not consecutive but are consistently spaced?

Tags: worksheet-function

I have a table that I need to sum the row information in every 4th cell indefinitely to allow for expansion of the sum area. The other 3 cells are for information only. Is this possible with a formula?

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
=SUM(IF(MOD(ROW(A1:A14),4)=1,A1:A14,0))
```

It checks all cells in range `A1:A14`, and for each of them it checks the "rest" of the row number modulo 4. In case this is 1 (this is true for the cases A1, A5, A9 and A13), the numbers are added.

Hereby an explanatory screenshot:

[image]